# Visual Studio 2013 IIS debugger settings

Tags: debugging, iis

I'm sure this question has been answered before, but I can't find it!

So, I just reverted to VS 2013 because my subscription to VS 2015 lapsed and suddenly I've got errors in my app that weren't there before. Specifically, this:

```
GET http://localhost:54/i18n/en.json 404 (Not Found)
```

What I've found on StackOverflow points me towards a path setting, but where I'd go to set it, I've got no idea. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Standard disclaimer: *really don't want to waste people's time, but since I've been on here for two years and still asked only 3 questions, I have to get my count up so I can at least thank people for their help. 11 to go...*

Answer (score 0):

finally found an answer and added it to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks for looking!